# Angular constructing a complex domain model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular JS, apologies if this question sound very basic, But i have a XML xsd model like below.

```
  public class Client {

    private String name;
    //A client can have n number of attachments
    private List<AttachmentDetails> attachmentList;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<AttachmentDetails> getAttachmentList() {
        return attachmentList;
    }
    public void setAttachmentList(List<AttachmentDetails> attachmentList) {
        this.attachmentList = attachmentList;
    }

}

public class AttachmentDetails {
    //File URL
    private String url;
    //File Name
    private String name;
    //Attachment data
    private AtttachmentData attachmentData;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public AtttachmentData getAttachmentData() {
        return attachmentData;
    }
    public void setAttachmentData(AtttachmentData attachmentData) {
        this.attachmentData = attachmentData;
    }


}

public class AtttachmentData {
    //PK in the table
    private String id;
    //File data
    private byte[] data;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

As you can see from the model, a client can have n number attachments, which are then editable and saved to database, I could contruct Client, but struggling to understand how to contruct list of attachment details with a attachementdata (File data) inside it, using agular techniques.

Please can someone help? An example of the above could be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a regular JS object:

```
client = {
  name: 'client name',
  attachments: []
};

client.attachments.push({
  url: 'your url',
  name: 'test.jpg'
});
```

If you are uploading files using `<input type=file>` then you will need to get the files property from the element in question and handle it yourself. Angular doesn't handle this well by itself and the common solution I have found is it use a directive.

Something like this:

```
myModule.directive('file', function () {
    var template = '<input type="file" name="files"  accept="image/jpeg" />';
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var selector = angular.element(template);
        elem.append(selector);
        selector.bind('change', function (event) {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope[attrs.file] = event.target.files[0];
            });
        });
        scope.$watch(attrs.file, function (file) {
            if (!file) selector.val(file);
        });
    };
});
```

And you would add it to your template like this:

```
<span file="attachment" ng-model="attachment"></span>
```

In your control you will now be able to access the the attachment from the scope:

```
$scope.attachment
```

and you can also reset input element by setting your model to null

```
$scope.attachment = null
```

which is handy if you are reusing the form (in fact the directive is redundant apart from the purpose, really just need to hook into the change event and get a reference to the file from there)

And you can upload that to the server or do what you like with it.

Comment: ok Thanks,As far as the functionality, We display Client html page, then Client logs into this page, uploads 1 to many attachements, by using <input type=file> option with add/delete button to add attachments, and submits the form. Thats all the functionality required is.

Comment: updated the answer with details of how to get the file, you obviously will need to have a controller and methods to handle adding and upload, but I think this answers the original question of how to construct the model and handle files in angular